# Git: copy part of branch to another branch

Tags: git, svn, version-control, branch, rebase

Let's say we have versions that are on separate branches.

- master
- v1
- v2

Our workflow with SVN was that we made bug repairs on master and then merged them into v1 and v2, new features should wait until next version (v3) is created.

This is how it looks after SVN to GIT conversion

```
                      ---v2----v2----v2
                     /
M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M
\
 v1----v1----v1----v1---v1---v1
```

M is master, v1 and v2 are version branches.

Now let's say that someone will push commits "c" and "c1" on master.

```
                      ---v2----v2----v2                c1---c1---c1
                     /                                /            \
M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M---c---c---c---c---c--c
\
 v1----v1----v1----v1---v1---v1
```

How do you copy the part of the branch containing "c" and "c1" commits into v1?

Expected result:

```
                      ---v2----v2----v2                c1---c1---c1
                     /                                /            \
M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M---c---c---c---c---c--c
\                                        c1---c1---c1
 \                                      /            \
  v1----v1----v1----v1---v1---v1---c---c---c---c---c--c
```

I found out that cherry-pick lets me pick single commits and reapply them whenever I want. I think that rebase does what I want but I'm lost in rebase's arguments.

This his how I think it should work:

- pull everything to local repo
- rebase c+c1 commits into v1 or v2
- push to our "central" repo

Also, if there's another workflow alternative that would work for us, I'm really open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think easiest way to receive expected result `git cherry-pick` or `git format-patch`:

```
# cherry-pick example
git checkout v1
git cherry-pick c
git cherry-pick c1
...

# patch example
git checkout master
git format-patch HEAD~3
git checkout v1 && git am *.patch
```

With rebase you do not get the result that expect:

```
                      ---v2----v2----v2                c1---c1---c1
                     /                                /            \
M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M----M---c---c---c---c---c--c
^                                                                    \
your current v1 base                                                  \
                                                                       v1----v1----v1----v1---v1---v1
                                                                    ^
                                                                    v1 base after rebase
```